# Creating tooltip for multiple buttons

Tags: c#, winforms, tooltip, oledb

This code(below) suppose to add information to  ToolTips which are taken from database(and the class Codons does it(it is the part that actually works)). I tried to do it in FOR loop, but it is warning me about this line:

```
toolTip1.SetToolTip(Convert.ToString(letter),"Name: "+fullname+" ("+cdn.GetCodon1()+")"
                          +"\n Begin: "+cdn.GetStart()+", End: "+cdn.GetEnd()+"");
```

I have 20 buttons which are named in a-z letters, except 6 specific letters(see the IF inside the FOR)

Here is the CODE:

```
private void UpdateToolTipButton()
{
  string fullname;
  Codons cdn;
  char letter='a';
  //get info about every amino acid from database
  OleDbConnection  dataConnection = new OleDbConnection();
  dataConnection.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Projects_2012\\Project_Noam\\Access\\myProject.accdb";
  dataConnection.Open();
  for(int i=1;i<=26;i++,letter++)
  {
    if((letter!='b')&&(letter!='e' )&& (letter!='j') && (letter!='o')&& (letter!='u') && (letter!='z'))
    {
      OleDbCommand datacommand = new OleDbCommand();
      datacommand.Connection = dataConnection;
      datacommand.CommandText = "SELECT tblCodons.codonsFullName"
                     +" FROM tblCodons"
                     +" WHERE tblCodons.codonsCodon1="+letter;   

      OleDbDataReader dataReader = datacommand.ExecuteReader();
      dataReader.Read();
      fullname = dataReader.GetString(0);
      cdn = new Codons(fullname);

      toolTip1.SetToolTip(Convert.ToString(letter),"Name: "+fullname+" ("+cdn.GetCodon1()+")"
                          +"\n Begin: "+cdn.GetStart()+", End: "+cdn.GetEnd()+"");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: BTW, can you please let me know what is the warning message does it throw?

Comment: You say "it is warning me about this line"; could you add what the warning message is, exactly?

Comment: in your sql statement you didn't put single quotes around letter, should be Where codonsCodon1 = '" + letter + "'"

Comment: Error 2 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip.SetToolTip(System.Windows.Forms.Control, string)' has some invalid arguments C:\Projects_2012\Project_Noam\Project\myProject\myProject\AdProtein.cs 120 13 myProject

Comment: @user1266429 That error (not warning) message tells you what's wrong. Have a look at [the documentation for `SetToolTip()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.settooltip.aspx).

Comment: So, the method signature is [`SetToolTip(Control, String)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.settooltip.aspx), but you are trying to pass two strings?

Comment: How did you create your buttons, in Visual studio designer, or you created them during runtime?

Comment: in the visual designer. i don't know how to get access to the control by strings.thats what i actually ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SetToolTip is looking for a *control* as the first argument.  You are supplying `Convert.ToString(letter)`.

The first argument needs to be the button you want to have the tooltip:

```
toolTip1.SetToolTip(button1, "Name: " + fullname);
```

I'm guessing you were trying to set the title of the ToolTip, in which case, that's not part of the SetToolTip method.  You would have to set the property yourself:

```
toolTip1.ToolTipTitle = Convert.ToString(letter);
```

If your *buttons* are those letters, then you would reference them by their name as the control key:

```
  if (this.Controls.ContainsKey(Convert.ToString(letter))) {
    toolTip1.SetToolTip(this.Controls[Convert.ToString(letter)], "Name: " + fullname + " etc(";
  }
```

Comment: i'm trying to find a way to use strings as controls. How can i do that and also to set the tool tip?

Comment: @user1266429 *strings as controls?*  I don't know what that means.  Are you saying you have a button named 'a' and a button named 'b'?  If so, I updated the answer.

Comment: yes.(except of the b specificly). and i'm trying to use tooltip by with string(actually a char) that contains the name of the button.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't open a new reader for every item, you were also missing single quotes around an item in the where clause, but the where clause isn't necessary anyway `\(^_^)_/`

anyway, this is my Solution.

```
private char _letter;

private string _fullName;

public char Letter{
get{
return _letter;
}
set{
_letter = value;
}
}
public string FullName{
get{
return _fullName;
}
set{
_fullName = value;
}
}

Private Void UpdateToolTipButton(){
string fullname;
codons cdn;
char letter;
OleDbConnection iConnect = new OleDbConnection();
iConnect.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data 
Source=@"C:\Projects_2012\Project_Noam\Access\myProject.accdb";

OleDbCommand iCommand = new OldDbCommand("Select * from  tblCodons",iConnect);
List<YourClassName> iList = new List<YourClassName>();

OleDbDataReader iRead = null;
iRead = iCommand.ExecuteReader();
while(iRead.Read()){
YourClassName iClass = new YourClassName();
iClass.Letter = Convert.ToChar(iRead["codonsCodon1"]);
iClass.FullName = Convert.ToString(iRead["codonsFullName"]);
iList.Add(iClass);
}
iConnect.Close();
iRead.Close();

foreach(var VarName in iList)
{
toolTip1.SetToolTip(button1, "Name: " + var.FullName);
toolTip1.ToolTipTitle = var.Letter;

}
}
```

Comment: ahh, i assumed that the syntax of his .SetToolTip was right,
anyway this is just a cleanup, no need to create int i when you can increment char, and no need to open a reader for each item in the for loop

Comment: i didn't understand what should i write indtead 'YourClassName'.I use only one class in the program; Codons

Comment: There we go, should be fixed now., the class name is assuming you wrote this method within a class, i guess if you did you can't put the foreach within the method, you would have to make it return the list and write the foreach within your UI app

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right, your Form has multiple buttons, with their `Text` properties set to letters `a-z`. the problem is that `SetToolip` needs the control (button) as its first parameter in order to set its tooltip, but you are passing button's text value instead.

Your loop should be arranged into something like this, so that you can iterate through actual buttons:

```
foreach (var button in GetButtons())
{
    if (ShouldSetTooltip(button)) 
    {
        // ...
        tooltip.SetTooltip(button, text);
    }
}
```

To get all buttons placed in your form (or on a panel), you can use something like:

```
private IEnumerable<Button> GetButtons()
{
    // this is where you decide which buttons to return
    foreach (var c in this.Controls) // or panel1.Controls
        if (c is Button)
            yield return (Button)c;
}
```

And then you will probably need to add your check to skip certain button names:

```
private bool ShouldSetTooltip(Control c)
{
    string[] lettersToSkip = new string[] { "b","e","o","u","j","z" };
    return lettersToSkip.Contains(c.Text) == false;
}
```

**[Edit]**

If you want to get the control by its **Name** property (note: this is not the same as the `Text` property), you can use you loop and write it like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 26; i++, letter++)
{
    ...
    var button = this.Controls[letter.ToString()];
    var txt = "Name: "+fullname+" ("+cdn.GetCodon1()+")"
              +"\n Begin: "+cdn.GetStart()+", End: "+cdn.GetEnd()+"";

    toolTip1.SetToolTip(button, txt);
}
```

Comment: i didn't understand the "GetButtons"

Comment: @user1266429: `GetButtons` iterates through all controls in your form, and returns only those controls which are of type `Button` (you probably have other controls also, labels, combo boxes, etc).

Comment: @user1266429: ok, I edited my answer. If you want to get the control by its name, you can index the `Controls` property.